# how to convert string output into executable commands

Tags: import

```
temp = (layer = #;
    layerS = ToString[#];
    StringForm["Import[\"drainCdg_gdat0``\",\"Table\"]", 
     layerS]) & /@ {1, 2, 3}
```

how to get the output of this to actually execute Import command? i.e. go to a directory and import a series of files with indexed filenames ?

Comment: You've seen `ToExpression[]`?

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to use StringForm if you want to turn these strings into expressions. StringForm only changes the display. See StringJoin.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Agreed. Also, if one would insist in using `StringForm`, the preceding `ToString` would be fully unnecessary. StringForm doesn't need strings for its slots.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I wonder if there is a convenient way at all to work with StringForm. Ah I see I need to edit my answer a bit.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom You can throw `ToString` on `StringForm`. This will turn it into a proper string.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Ah, thanks. I think I tried that but did something silly and got an error. Now I see it works.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
heldImports = 
 Import["drainCdg_gdat0" <> ToString[#], "Table"] & /@ Hold[1, 2, 3]
```

> Hold[(Import["drainCdg_gdat0" <> ToString[#1], "Table"] &)[1],
>  (Import["drainCdg_gdat0" <> ToString[#1], "Table"] &)[2],
>  (Import["drainCdg_gdat0" <> ToString[#1], "Table"] &)[3]]

and then

```
thisAndThatTable = heldImports[[1]]
```

Or, maybe more conventionally

```
heldImports = 
 Import @@@ (Hold @@ ({"drainCdg_gdat0" <> ToString[#], 
        "Table"} & /@ {1, 2, 3}))
```

> Hold[Import["drainCdg_gdat01", "Table"], 
>    Import["drainCdg_gdat02", "Table"], 
>    Import["drainCdg_gdat03", "Table"]]

Note that `<>` stands for `StringJoin`.

You could have done something similar with `ToExpression`. Just don't use `StringForm`. To see that StringForm is bad for this purpose, note that

```
StringForm["Import[\"drainCdg_gdat0``\",\"Table\"]", 1] // FullForm
```

> StringForm["Import[\"drainCdg_gdat0``\",\"Table\"]",1]

The following is an example using `ToExpression`

```
importStrings = 
  "Import[\"drainCdg_gdat0" <> ToString[#] <> "\",\"Table\"]" & /@ {1,
     2, 3}
```

> {"Import[\"drainCdg_gdat01\",\"Table\"]", 
>   "Import[\"drainCdg_gdat02\",\"Table\"]", 
> "Import[\"drainCdg_gdat03\",
>   \"Table\"]"}

```
import[i_] := ToExpression[importStrings[[i]]];

suchAndSuchTable = import[2];
```

You can use `SetDirectory["dir"]` to go to the relevant directory. Or you can prepend the path to the filename using `StringJoin` (`<>`), or you can just write `"/dir1/dir2/drainCdg_gdat02"` of course.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to do is "go to a directory and import a series of files with indexed filenames" there is a simpler way. Say you want to import all the .tif files in a directory with address `path`.

```
fileNames = FileNames["*.tif", path];
allFiles = Table[Import[fileNames[[num]]], {num, 1, Length[fileNames]}];
```

This imports them all at once and they can be indexed as `allFiles[[1]]`, `allFiles[[2]]`, etc. More generally, you can build a list of all the file names and then import the whole list. More succinctly, you can write

```
allFiles = Import /@ fileNames
```

to get the same result.