# StringForm and NotebookWrite

Tags: notebooks

I'm trying to get my head around NotebookWrite for the last few days. I can't understand why

```
NotebookWrite[nb,
  Cell[
   StringForm["some text = ``", 3]
  , "Text"
   ]]
```

doesn't seem to produce what I would expect:

some text = 3

in the newly defined notebook nb.

Why is this? How can this be achieved?
Thanks all, once again!

Comment: This is not a problem of `NotebookWrite` but of `Cell` with `StringForm`. Check out `Cell`-s [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cell.html) under **Details** and **"The contents of cells can be the following"**. As you will see, `StringForm` is not listed, so you either have to convert it to a normal string (e.g. using `ToString@3`) or to some `xxxData` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Istvan Zachar's comment is correct, but I think it does not cover your main confusion. The key observation here is that even though it seems like your `StringForm` expression evaluates to a string, it actually gets displayed that way by front end. To see what the expression looks like to *Mathematica*, you can do

```
StringForm["some text = ``", 3] // FullForm
```

which just gives

> ```
> (*output*)
> StringForm["some text = ``",3]
> ```

So *Mathematica* sees this expression with head `StringForm`, rather than a string. So if we do for example

```
Head[StringForm["some text = ``",3]]
```

we get `StringForm`, whereas if we do

```
Head["some text = 3"]
```

we get `String`.

Note that it is possible to use `ToString` on an expression with `Head` `StringForm` to get a real `String`. Also, as mentioned in another answer of mine in a question of yours, you should considered using boxes rather than just strings inside your `Cell`'s

Closely related: [how to convert string output into executable commands](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26323/4330)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll take a look a the link!